# webpack nodeExternals - regex to allow anything but css files in specific directory

Tags: regex, webpack

Trying to prevent css files from one specific npm package from being bundled. So far I have a regex that prevents everything in `node_modules/@foo/bar` from being bundled, but I only want to prevent css files in this directory, and all subdirectories.

```
externals: [
        nodeExternals({
          allowlist: [/^(?!@foo\/bar).*$/i]
        }),
      ],
```

What regex do I need to do this?

Update:
https://regex101.com/r/YgkQw5/1 seems to be the correct regex but I'm still getting css files bundled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match up to the `.css` at the end of string:

```js
externals: [
        nodeExternals({
          allowlist: [/^(?!@foo\/bar.*\.css$).*/i]
        }),
      ],
```

The `^(?!@foo\/bar.*\.css$).*` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!@foo\/bar.*\.css$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

  - `@foo\/bar` - a `@foo\/bar` string
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `\.css` - a `.css` text at the...
  - `$` - end of string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YgkQw5/1).

Comment: I can see your demo working, but the css files are still being bundled.